# Access Flyout from button inside Flyout XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I feel this is a rookie XAML question, but here goes.

**What I want to do:**
I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 App, and I want to add functionality to a custom-flyout, such that clicking the same menu-button in the flyout two times in a row, closes the flyout. 
Example: User clicks the "Goto settings" menu-item in the flyout. If the user now clicks it again, it would mean that we are already in the settings-menu, thus I just want to close the flyout instead.

**Problem:**
My problem is that I need some way to be able to call code inside the flyout, when a button inside it is clicked. I have no option of doing any code-behind here, as I'm working with MVVMCross and Xamarin (and I dont want to move windows-phone specific logic into the general-for-all-platforms viewmodels).

**Tried so far:**
I have tried fixing this by making a custom button that inherits from Button. When the button loads, an event is subscribed to its tapped event. When this happens, I try to get a handle to the flyout by recursively looking at the parent (and then parent's parent) of the button, until I find it.
...This did not work, since I never get the Flyout as a parent, instead I get a Flyout-presenter (which does not give me access to my custom flyout), so I could not call the functions I wanted here.

I have tried making a custom "FlyoutButton" that inherits from Button. This button has a DependencyProperty for the Flyout that can be set in the XAML, so I have a handle to the flyout inside the button. 
When I try to do this however, I only get the exception "System.Void cannot be used from C#", which I really cannot figure out, why I get. Below is how my code for it looks.

**My code:**
*XAML snippet:*

```
<Button.Flyout>
   <controls:MainMenuFlyout x:Name="test"
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <controls:MainMenuButton MainMenuFlyout="{Binding ElementName=test}" Grid.Row="0"/>
      <controls:MainMenuButton MainMenuFlyout="{Binding ElementName=test}" Grid.Row="0"/>
      <controls:MainMenuButton MainMenuFlyout="{Binding ElementName=test}" Grid.Row="0"/>
   <controls:MainMenuFlyout />
<Button.Flyout />
```

*C#:*

```
public class MainMenuButton : Button
    {
        public static DependencyProperty MainMenuFlyoutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MainMenuFlyout", typeof(MainMenuFlyout), typeof(MainMenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, MainMenuFlyoutPropertyChangedCallback));

        public static void SetMainMenuFlyout(UIElement element, MainMenuFlyout value)
        {
            element.SetValue(MainMenuFlyoutProperty, value);
        }

        public MainMenuFlyout GetMainMenuFlyout(UIElement element)
        {
            return (MainMenuFlyout)element.GetValue(MainMenuFlyoutProperty);
        }

        private static void MainMenuFlyoutPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your dependency property declaration is wrong. Instead of declaring static getter and setter methods (as you would do for an attached property), you should declare a `public MainMenuFlyout MainMenuFlyout` property with getter/setter that call GetValue and SetValue.

Comment: Besides that `string.Empty` is an invalid default value for a property of type MainMenuFlyout.

Comment: Thanks alot! You were right in your feedback, and the changes worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency property declaration is wrong. Is should look like this, with a regular property wrapper instead of static getter and setter method, and `null` as default property value, instead of `string.Empty`:

```
public static DependencyProperty MainMenuFlyoutProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MainMenuFlyout", typeof(MainMenuFlyout), typeof(MainMenuButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, MainMenuFlyoutPropertyChangedCallback));

public MainMenuFlyout MainMenuFlyout
{
    get { return (MainMenuFlyout)GetValue(MainMenuFlyoutProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MainMenuFlyoutProperty, value); }
}
```